# Problems installing jre-6u30-windows-i586.exe on a Windows 7 x64 system

Tags: windows, java, sccm-2007

When I try to install jre-6u30-windows-i586.exe on a Windows 7 x64 system using the NT Authority\System account, I get a 1619 error ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385(v=vs.85).aspx) returned to the starting process.  I've run the installation using SCCM and using PSEXEC -S and both ways return the same errors.

```
Command line used: jre-6u30-windows-i586.exe /s /v "/qn /norestart /lvx C:\temp\JRE630.log ADDLOCAL=ALL IEXPLORER=1  REBOOT=Suppress JAVAUPDATE=0 INSTALLDIR=\c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\"  SOURCEDIR=\"C:\temp\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30\""
```

When I enable verbose logging I see the following:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 5/16/2012  21:09:52  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:691]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:691]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:691]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30\jre1.6.0_30.msi          ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:691]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:691]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:706]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:706]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:722]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:722]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30\jre1.6.0_30.msi
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:722]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (38:64) [21:09:52:737]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (38:64) [21:09:52:737]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (38:64) [21:09:52:737]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30\jre1.6.0_30.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (38:64) [21:09:52:737]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30\jre1.6.0_30.msi 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (38:64) [21:09:52:737]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (38:04) [21:09:52:737]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:737]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (D0:A4) [21:09:52:737]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
=== Verbose logging stopped: 5/16/2012  21:09:52 ===
```

This looks like it is attempting to extract the MSI to "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30" but it is not able to extra the MSI from the executable so the installation fails.  Is there any way to get this to work?

Thanks in advance,

Keith

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can get this to work by creating the necessary directory ahead of time and then adding a junction point from the 64-bit profile to the 32-bit profile, like this:

```
mklink /J c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30 c:\windows\syswow64\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_30
```

More detail can be found on my blog [here](http://harryjohnston.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/installing-32-bit-software-as-system-in-windows-7-x64/).

(Incidentally, if you had tagged this question 'windows' I'd have answered it much sooner!)

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6995830

This is a known issue.  The package extracts to the syswow64 folder, but looks for the newly created msi in the system32 folder.

Apparently when they say 'i586' they mean it ONLY installs on a 32bit os/system.

Comment: +1 for referencing the bug report, but note that the installer works perfectly well if you run it in the context of a real user.